# Pip is broken and I don't have admin permission

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I have poured about 6 hours into this issue now and I'm getting farther and farther. Here's what happened.

I am using a shared Linux machine that has both Python 2.7 and Python 3.5 and I don't have admin privileges. I was using Python 3.5 and I  wanted to use the package seaborn and I found out the specific labeling feature I wanted was only available in a newer version. So no problem "pip3 install seaborn --upgrade".

Everything was happening so fast but something went wrong and by the suggestion of the internet, I ended up upgrading a few other packages like matplotlib, setuptools, and eventually pip itself.

Here's where it really went wrong. Pip just broke. This happens when I run pip3 --version:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/__init__.py", line 33, in vendored
    __import__(vendored_name, globals(), locals(), level=0)
ImportError: No module named 'pip._vendor.pkg_resources'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip3", line 9, in <module>
    from pip import main
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from pip.exceptions import InstallationError, CommandError, PipError
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/exceptions.py", line 6, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.six import iteritems
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/__init__.py", line 75, in <module>
    vendored("pkg_resources")
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/__init__.py", line 36, in vendored
    __import__(modulename, globals(), locals(), level=0)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 664, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 634, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pkg_resources-0.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2927, in <module>
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pkg_resources-0.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2913, in _call_aside
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pkg_resources-0.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2952, in _initialize_master_working_set
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pkg_resources-0.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 956, in subscribe
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pkg_resources-0.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2952, in <lambda>
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pkg_resources-0.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2515, in activate
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pkg_resources-0.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2097, in declare_namespace
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pkg_resources-0.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2047, in _handle_ns
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pkg_resources-0.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2066, in _rebuild_mod_path
AttributeError: '_NamespacePath' object has no attribute 'sort'
```

The first line in the call stack is "from pip import main" so I tried running pip --version instead of pip3 and now I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip", line 9, in <module>
    from pip import main
ImportError: cannot import name main
```

This error is all over the internet as a bug in pip itself but all every solution involves something that I don't have permission to do. I tried to uninstall and reinstall an older version of pip using "python -m pip ..." but this did not help with the pip3 error, which prompted the same error a few lines later. And I can't use this shortcut with pip3 (python3 -m pip...) because this error occurs anyway.

Worst part is that my original program is now completely dead. I can't even import seaborn at all without crashing.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/u/hailey/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 861, in __setitem__
    cval = self.validate[key](val)
KeyError: 'axes.color_cycle'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "nn.py", line 9, in <module>
    import seaborn as sns
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/seaborn/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    set()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/seaborn/rcmod.py", line 98, in set
    set_palette(palette, color_codes=color_codes)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/seaborn/rcmod.py", line 491, in set_palette
    mpl.rcParams["axes.color_cycle"] = list(colors)
  File "/u/hailey/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 868, in __setitem__
    'list of valid parameters.' % (key,))
KeyError: 'axes.color_cycle is not a valid rc parameter. See rcParams.keys() for a list of valid parameters.'
```

At this point, I decided everything would be easier if I just downloaded my own clean version of Python in a local directory where I have privileges. So I downloaded and set up a new version of Python 3.6 in a local directory. Then I ran my original program with this and I was told I had no module named 'numpy'. Reasonable. Let's try to install numpy.

```
Obtaining file:///u/hailey/python36/Python-3.6.0
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/u/hailey/python36/Python-3.6.0/setup.py", line 4, in <module>
        import sys, os, importlib.machinery, re, optparse
    ImportError: No module named machinery

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /u/hailey/python36/Python-3.6.0/
```

Now I'm led to a page that recommends running "setup.py install", which sounds simple enough. But nope.

```
bash: /u/hailey/python36/Python-3.6.0/setup.py: Permission denied
```

Now I'm giving up because evidently I know nothing about Python. I would really appreciate some help with this. At this point, even just recovering the state I had yesterday would be fine as I can live without the extra label on my seaborn graph. Thanks everyone!

Comment: It sounds like various things in your system's python installation might be hosed. And, with no offense intended, chances are whatever you've only made things worse for yourself by trying stuff without knowing what you're doing (I hope at least some of it was educational). If this is a machine you don't have admin on, surely somebody does. Do you not have a local system administrator who can help you sort things out? This feels like the kind of issue where someone with knowledge needs to sit down at the machine and poke around a bit to see what's broke.

Comment: Also I strongly recommend looking at what environment variables you have set. You can print your environment with `env | sort` at the shell prompt. Look at things like `PATH` and `PYTHONPATH` in particular because you are likely mixing up different Python installations. I also suggest googling "virtualenv" and spending a bit of time learning about that. It is the cleanest, safest way to manage different stacks of Python libraries for different projects (as well as install your own packages).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My environment variables are all sorted out thankfully so that isn't the issue. I definitely need to learn to use virtualenv though. Drafting an email to the admin now.

Comment: With virtualenv you can use your system's Python, but in a totally clean environment where no packages are installed, or you can start from the packages already installed on the system but override them. I would also recommend looking into Anaconda if you just want your own complete Python install that you can play around with locally.

Comment: I would second the suggestion of just [downloading the Anaconda distribution](https://www.anaconda.com/download/#linux) and working with [`conda` environments](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html), which is an alternative to virtualenv. Hopefully, this will be segregated enough from your other installations and the system Python that it will just work. Oh, and it comes with all these libraries already...